# Find 2 imaginary numbers that have a cosine of 4, using $\cos z =\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

> Use the definition 
>   $$
> \cos z =\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
> $$
>   to find $2$ imaginary numbers having a cosine of $4$.

I tried two approaches, both of which ended in failure:

$$
8=e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\\
\ln8=0\\
\\
\space
\\
8=\cos z+i\sin z+\cos z-i\sin z\\
z = \arccos4
$$

What approach should I take instead?

Comment: @Integrator huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using $\log$ incorrectly, even in the real sense. It's not true, for instance, that $\log\left(e+e^{-1}\right)=0$.

**Hint:** Instead, multiply both sides of $8=e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$ by $e^{iz}$ and solve the resulting quadratic in $e^{iz}$.

Comment: Thanks. When I complete the square I get $iz=\ln(4\pm i\sqrt{15})$, but the answer listed is $i\ln(4\pm\sqrt{15})$. Is it acceptable to extract out the $i$ like that?

Comment: @hohner I take you already got it since you accepted my answer. In any case you should be getting $e^{iz}=4\pm \sqrt{15}$, thus $iz=\log\left(4\pm \sqrt{15}\right)$.

Comment: The quadratic I got is $e^{2iz}-8e^{iz}+1$. Completing the square gives $e^{iz}=4\pm i\sqrt{15}$ right? The answer lists $\sqrt{15}$ not $i\sqrt{15}$

Comment: @hohner The quadratic is correct, however $$\left(e^{iz}\right)^2-8e^{iz}+1=0\iff e^{iz}=\underbrace{\dfrac{-(-8)\pm \sqrt{8^2-4}}2}_{=4\pm \sqrt{15}},$$ by the [quadratic formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033893/find-2-imaginary-numbers-that-have-a-cosine-of-4-using-cos-z-fraceize).

Comment: Ah okay. And I suppose if $iz=\log(4\pm\sqrt{15})$, the $i$ becomes interchangeable on both sides?

Comment: @hohner Yes, but the reason is that at the start, instead of multiplying by $e^{iz}$, they multiplied by $e^{-iz}$. The resulting polynomial is the same, but the variable is different.

Answer (score 0):

$u=e^{ix}$
${{u+{1\over{u}}}\over2}=4$
$u+{1\over{u}}=8$
$u^2+1=8u$
$u^2-8u+1=0$
$u=e^{ix}={{8\pm\sqrt{60}}\over2}
={{8\pm{2\sqrt{15}}}\over2}
={4\pm\sqrt{15}}$
$ix=\ln(4\pm\sqrt{15})$
$x={\ln(4\pm\sqrt{15})\over{i}}
=-i\ln(4\pm\sqrt{15})$